# Remote package repository of Miktex in Windows 7 not working

Tags: errors, packages, miktex2.9

I am facing a weird problem. The last time I ran any `.tex` file was 24 hours ago. It ran perfectly then but now today I have tried to run another `.tex file` and there are errors (please see the attached image).

The Remote Package Repository shows blank. No options of CTAN servers are present and ultimately, it shows a connection to api2.miktex.org could not be established. Note here that my net connection is perfectly fine. I am using the same net connection whilst I am writing and uploading this. I am not using any proxy. Two days ago everything is fine with this same (home) wi-fi net connection.

The initial code of the .tex file is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,preprint,superscriptaddress,floatfix,showpacs]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}  %Input what you want e.g., é, ł, a, ü
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}     %Output what you want e.g., é, ł, a, ü
\usepackage[british]{babel}  %Do hyphenation according to british english
\usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}\linespread{1.05}  %Palatino font
\usepackage[scaled=0.86]{berasans}  % URL font that go well wtih palatino
%\usepackage[scaled=1.03]{inconsolata} %Monospace font
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}  %Hyperlinks (pink, green, blue)
\usepackage{graphicx} % Package to insert exteral figures
\usepackage[babel]{microtype}  %Improves text justification
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,bm,amsfonts,mathrsfs,bbm} %Useful math packages
\usepackage{xspace}  %Useful to add space in macros
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{braket}
```

This is how my window looks:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me a couple of days this week. It might be related with the failure of google services in several countries.
Choose `Install from: a random package repository ...`

[image: google]

If you do not have the revtex4-2.cls installed you should install the package `revtex4` from MiKTeX console.

The clas  should be in

```
  ("C:/Program Files/MiKTeX/tex/latex/revtex/revtex4-2.cls"
  Document Class: revtex4-2 2019/01/18/14:29:48 4.2c    (https://journals.aps.org/revtex/ for documentation)
```